# Can't absolute position an image in Swiper.js

Tags: reactjs, overflow, hidden, swiper.js, absolute

I am trying to position an image inside a Swiper slider, and I need it to overflow the Swiper Container which has an overflow of hidden and display it on the bottom of another container. I am wondering is this possible to achieve?
[see actual design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7khl.png)

I have tried setting the Swiper Container to:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

and the .swiper-slide to:

```
.swiper-slide {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out, visibility 200ms ease-in-out;
}
```

so when the next slide come into play I trigger it back with:

```
.swiper-slide-active {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

sadly this method makes the scroll bar appear on the bottom of the page...
[see screenshot example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaown.png)

also I made a Codesandbox to keep the things simple [see codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-cookies-ckb45?file=/src/App.js)